# Adding javascript to a view?

Tags: views, javascript

I have a view in Drupal 7 that displays a list of all the nodes of a content type in alphabetical order. What would be the best way to implement javascript that only displays nodes starting with a specific letter, say, all nodes starting with the letter 'A'? I would also like to add a list of letters as links at the top to trigger the show/hide effects.

It's probably worth noting that I currently have javascript to achieve this using data gathered from an external database and implemented via a custom module. Ideally, I want the same functionality but want all the data to be coming from Drupal nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need a javascript way explicitly? Drupal can do these Filters and make the glossary view, an index by letters, at top for you already in the views administration area.